# How to get details coefficients on using PyWavelets?

Tags: python, pywavelets

I do understand how to use PyWavelets.For example if i have the following code:

```
cA,cD = pywt.dwt(yourResultA,'db3')
```

The value stored in cA and cD would be approximation coeff. and details coeff. respectively.
Is the value stored in cA that of 4th approximation coeff(A4) ?
Another problem that I am facing is that I want the values of all the details coeff i.e. D1,D2....D4. How can I get these values from cD?